Fantasy juvenile book from 1970s where one girl finds another hiding in the wall
I am trying to find a book read in the 1970s - early 1980s. Not sure when it was written. There were 2 girls, one named Amanda and one named Miranda (not the one by Scott Peck). I think the one girl was staying at a relative's house and discovered the other girl hiding in the wall.

I have not found this one, but I do have to say that I was not expecting there to be so many books about girls hiding in the walls.

I read a book in the 1970’s about a girl named Amanda, who stumbles upon an old painting of a girl who is identical to herself named Miranda. I don’t remember if it was herself from the past, or an ancestor of hers. There was a bit of mystery behind the plot, and I remember I really enjoyed it, I wanted to buy it present day for my granddaughter but can not remember title, and I’m having no luck finding it. I don’t remember the girl living behind a wall though. Are we thinking of same book??
